# Table and crosstab query on a form - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I have a form is Access that needs to edit data in a table, but also display corresponding info that is in a crosstab query. I know I cant edit the crosstab query, but I need to be able to edit the table. Whenever a make a query that includes my table and the data from the crosstab query, it makes the whole thing locked so I cannot edit. I have already set the recordset type to dynaset inconsistent updates.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Crosstabs,_forms_and_updating, I am by no means sure of the valuse of this and wonder whether you should just have a button to run the query.

Comment: Thanks, but that is a lot more complicated that what I am looking for. I didn't want to use a subform. I am sure there is a way to display data from both the table and query and still edit the table.